# How can I make an image span through multiple rows in Zurb-Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make a page via Foundation that lets users post articles, however, I'm having a problem. Here's what the page looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/60a2g5fn/ (be sure to expand the viewing window, or it will assume that you're on a mobile browser)

I'm required to post code after a JSFiddle link, so here's what the associated inputs/rows looks like.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label>Title
            <input type="text" name="HK_NEWS_TITLE">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label>Topstory Image</label>
        <select name="HK_NEWS_IMAGE">                        
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label>Slug
            <input type="text" name="HK_NEWS_SLUG">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label>Topstory Image Preview</label>
        <img src="http://www.pattiknows.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/love-man-woman-silhouette-sun-sunset-sea-lake-beach-300x187.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

The dropdown is where they can choose the images that uses PHP and Javascript to choose and append the image from a directory. Once they pick the image, it is appended under Topstory Image Preview, but it breaks the row and makes the slug have empty space below it.

[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaGbU.png) of the before, so you can compare. I want the image to be under Topstory Image Preview, but I don't want it to create unnecessary space below the Slug input bar.

Is there any way that I can do this? I've tried multiple things (aligning the image right out of the row, doesn't work. using css to make it the background-image, doesn't work). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using which you can achieve what you're trying to do. For the mobile layout, I believe it appears fine as it is but for the desktop layout, you can set the `position` of the image to `absolute` using `@media-queries` so that there's no empty white space to the left side of the image.

Here's a demo (view as full page):

```css
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  img#ts-preview {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.2/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.2/css/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form method="POST" action="news">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Title
        <input type="text" name="HK_NEWS_TITLE">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Topstory Image</label>
      <select name="HK_NEWS_IMAGE"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
      <label>Slug
        <input type="text" name="HK_NEWS_SLUG">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Topstory Image Preview</label>
      <img id="ts-preview" style="padding-bottom:20px;" src="http://www.pattiknows.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/love-man-woman-silhouette-sun-sunset-sea-lake-beach-300x187.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>Short Story
        <input type="text" name="HK_NEWS_SHORT">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>News Content</label>
      <textarea name="HK_NEWS_CONTENT"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes.